# How to calculate the number of elements in a string

Tags: r, string

I have a lot of strings of elements separated with hyphen `-`:

```
string<-c("aaa","aaa-bbb","aaa-bbb-ccc","aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd")
```

I want to calculate the number of elements in each string. The expected vector is

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Yes it answers my question when I set the pattern as  ```"-"```. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
sapply(strsplit(string, split = '-'), length)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```